# I have an OAuth backend that stores refresh tokens for an Android app - if the user uninstalls the app I have no way of deleting their refresh token

Tags: android, database, security, oauth, backend

So I want to create a backend that allows for indefinite persistent login for my Android app (like Facebook, Twitter, etc.) As such, I store a hash of the user's refresh token in my database and compare it to the client's refresh token every time a refresh is requested. If a client logs out, it sends a "api/logout" request which removes the refresh token. However, there's an edge case where if the user deletes the app without logging out, I have no way of revoking their refresh token from the database, so it sits their as stale data forever. Is there any way to deal with this case?

Comment: No, you cannot do it on client. The only robust way I can see to do it is using expiration time approach for tokens on your backend, and from time to time run some cleaner if there was no any interaction with client during set  period of time

Comment: refresh tokens that haven't been used in six months could just be deleted most auth server's revoke old unused tokens.   so assuming you are logging the last time they accessed your system this should work

Comment: @Kulebin  I created a cron job to accomplish this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a "logout" API that the client queues on log-out, which deletes the client's refresh token, and as well as a cron-job that runs every month that deletes refresh tokens that haven't been touched in 1 year+.